# Is `pickle.dump(d, f)` equivalent to `f.write(pickle.dumps(d))`?

Tags: python, pickle

Given an arbitrary picklable Python data structure `data`, is

```
with open('a', 'bw') as f:
    f.write(pickle.dumps(data))
```

equivalent to

```
with open('a', 'bw') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)
```

i.e. can I assume this equivalence when writing code? Could you describe how you reached to this conclusion?

The use-case is to separate serialization from writing, since I may want to write pickle to a non-disk location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent. Looking at the source code of [`pickle.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/pickle.py#L1584):

```
def _dump(obj, file, protocol=None, *, fix_imports=True):
    _Pickler(file, protocol, fix_imports=fix_imports).dump(obj)

def _dumps(obj, protocol=None, *, fix_imports=True):
    f = io.BytesIO()
    _Pickler(f, protocol, fix_imports=fix_imports).dump(obj)
    res = f.getvalue()
    assert isinstance(res, bytes_types)
    return res
```

`dumps` does the exact same thing as `dump`, just with an `io.BytesIO` object instead of a file object. It calls the internal `_Pickler().dump()` in the same way and simply returns the contents of the `io.BytesIO` object. Therefore, all `f.write(pickle.dumps(data))` does is first forward the result to an `io.BytesIO` object then to the actual file instead of writing to the file directly.

Answer (score 1):

They are not equivalent if an exception occurs during pickling. `f.write(pickle.dumps(data))` will not write anything to the file. Whereas     `pickle.dump(data, f)` will end up with a snapped or partial pickle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The [documentation of dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps) is pretty clear:

> Return the pickled representation of the object as a bytes object, instead of writing it to a file.

Writing the same representation to a file will be the same as calling `pickle.dump` directly.

Also, "file" here means anything with a `write` method, from [documentation of dump](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump):

> The file argument must have a write() method that accepts a single bytes argument. It can thus be an on-disk file opened for binary writing, an io.BytesIO instance, or any other custom object that meets this interface.